# Ex falso quodlibet with non well-formed formula or false interpretation?

Tags: logic

F $\vDash$ B, while B can be arbitrary. That is a well known theorem in classical logic. It is called *ex falso quodlibet* and basically says that from false premises any deduction is valid. But can B be really *literally* „arbitrary“ and still the argument holds valid? Two examples to explore the problem.

1. A $\land$~A $\vDash$ q vv p. Is this a valid argument since „q vv p“ is not a wff?

No. A $\land$~A $\nvDash$ q vv p. Because validity is defined: $\Sigma \vDash B \leftrightarrow \forall I:(\forall A \in \Sigma \to A(I) = 1) \to B(I) = 1$. But A, B just stand for wff‘s. So we cannot substitute „q vv p“ for B. But then we cannot arrive at A $\land$~A $\vDash$ q vv p which means that it is outside of the definition of validity.

2. 0=1 $\vDash_\Bbb N$ 7, but let us say that 7 gets interpreted here as a Seven-up bottle. Is this a valid argument despite that „7“ is not interpreted in the way we interpret in the realm of natural numbers?

Also no. 0=1 $\nvDash_\Bbb N$ 7. This time we begin from a slightly modified definition due to the situation: $\Sigma \vDash_\Bbb NB \leftrightarrow \forall I_\Bbb N:(\forall A \in \Sigma \to A(I _\Bbb N) = 1) \to B(I _\Bbb N) = 1$. Now, we cannot substitute our 7 (with the Seven-up interpretation) into B which only holds as a placeholder for wff‘s of a certain interpretation. So again, we cannot arrive where we want.

So in conclusion it seems imprecise to say that from false premises follow arbitrary sentences, we mean: arbitrary sentences *within* the structure and interpretation of the language we use. We can also never have a language for arbitrary structures and interpretations since we first need to define some structure and that means someone could use this very necessity to create some X that violates the structure and all of a sudden our language would not be arbitrary-powerful anymore because X would be outside of it.

Is this whole line of thinking correct in your opinion? Remarks?

Comment: Reductio ad absurdum. Common sense goes a long way.

Comment: How would this raa work?

Comment: "Seven-up interpretation"? Common sense does not use any "wff" and still goes a long way.

Comment: Obviously, the def applies to a formal language; if "xyz" is not a well-formed formula of the language, the expression $\bot \vDash \text {xyz}$ is meaningless. That's all.

Comment: Quite confused, also if basically correct. See [Semantic consequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Semantic_consequence): "A formula $A$ is a semantic consequence **within some formal system** $\mathcal {FS}$ of a set of statements $\Gamma$ [in symbols: $\Gamma \models _{\mathcal {FS}}A$], if and only if ...". So, YES: the def is relative to a formal system and thus to a language that specifies what is a correct formula.

Answer (score 4):

The conclusion can be an arbitrary sentence, but it must be a sentence. This is because the $\vDash$ relation is defined to hold between sentences (well-formed formulas), putting anything else around it is not a proper usage of the symbol. Generally only the well-formed formulas are ever of interest in logic, malformed examples like $q \lor \lor p$ are never considered once the language is staked out, "formula" always implicitly means "well-formed formula".

$q \lor \lor p$ is not a well-formed formula, so $p \land \neg p \vDash q \lor \lor p$ is ungrammatical and not meaningful.

$7$ is not a formula, but a term, so $0=1 \vDash 7$ is ungrammatical and not meaningful.

Both examples are excluded for purely syntactic reasons because they do not meet the definition of "well-formed formula". This is completely independent of interpretations, which only enter once we have syntactically well-defined input to begin with.

So your suspicion as to why the examples are excluded is correct, it's just that "arbitrary sentences" *means* "arbitrary well-formed formulas" and thus correctly captures the intended scpoe, and structures and interpretations are out of the picture at this point because they are only defined for sentences, which the malformed conclusions are not.

---

$\ldots \vDash_{\mathbb{N}} \ldots$, be the way, is meaningless as well. The $\vDash$ relation is *defined* as preservation of truth in *every* possible structure; there is no such thing as restricting logical consequence to just the structure of the natural numbers.
Also,  as a notational remark, $\mathbb{N}$ is not a structure, but a set; for the structure with $\mathbb{N}$ as the domain and an intended interpretation $\mathcal{I}$ of the symbols one typically writes $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: So what do you say to this: $0=1 \vDash 2+2=5$. You‘d probably say at first glance that it is correct and a valid argument. Do you change your opinion if I would tell you that I interpret „2+2=5“ as „Socrates is mortal“ despite that the standard interpretation interprets „2+2=5“ as addition of natural numbers? IMO you‘d have to say: the argument is valid, but NOT if you use your interpretation.

Comment: Precisely because, as you show, we can easily make up a structure where the premise is true but the conclusion is false, and of course these structures count as well - as I wrote above, "valid" *means* "in every possible interpretation", and not just some intended interpretation you cherry-pick  - there is no reason to believe this argument would be valid (it is not).

Comment: That's my point: There is no meaning of "validity"/"$\vDash$" that is restricted to just one structure, the quantification over all interpretations is part of its definition. If you mean to say that at least one of the premises is false or the conclusion true in one particular structure, then that's truth, *not* validity.

Answer (score 0):

> A $\land$~A $\vDash$ q vv p. Is this a valid argument since „q vv p“
> is not a wff?

No. The theorem $A\land \neg A \implies B$ could only have been derived (as below) by first implicitly assuming that $A$  and $B$ are arbitrary logical propositions.

As for the validity of this argument, we have:

> A deductive argument is said to be valid if and only if it takes a
> form that makes it impossible for the premises to be true and the
> conclusion nevertheless to be false. Otherwise, a deductive argument
> is said to be invalid. [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/val-snd/)

The above argument is valid because the antecedent is always false. As such, we could never infer from this argument alone that $B$ is true.

---

Here is a formal proof of the Principle of Explosion (*ex falso quodlibet*) for arbitrary propositions $A$ and $B$ using a simplified form of natural deduction.  (Screenshot from my proof checker):

[image]

---

Alternatively and perhaps more easily applicable in proofs:

[image]